# PHP: A "Rank" System

Tags: php, mysql, profile, rank

I have a mysql database that consists of users. In that database, there is a "score" column. I want to make a profile for the users, but it will show their rank. I don't want to do this server-sided, so i'm trying to do it from the profile page itself. This is my current code:

```
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY score DESC") or die("Could not allocate information!");
$rank = 0;
while(mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)){
  $rank++;
}
echo "<b>Rank: </b>#$rank<br/>";
```

Ive also tried:

```
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY score DESC") or die("Could not allocate information!");
$rank = 0;
while(mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)){
  $rank++;
  echo "<b>Rank: </b>#$rank<br/>";
}
```

Either way out, every user has the same rank, #2. Is there any way for me to do this? And if you need more information, please just comment, don't down-rep me. Thanks.

Comment: Try `echo`ing inside the `while` loop, just after setting `$rank`. In your second try, you used `$num` instead of `$rank`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1190388) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [tag:PDO] or [tag:MySQLi].

Comment: Sorry guys, I fixed my code. It use to be num, but its now rank. Either way out, it is still showing everybody as rank 2, and if I add the echo in the while, they get ranks 1-2(I have 2 users).

Comment: Don't you expect them to get ranks 1 and 2 when echoing in the while?

Comment: Have you considered using the `mysql_num_rows()` function, instead of fetching results in a loop without using them?

Comment: Not exactly. I want the user with the most score(50000) to be "Rank: #1" and the user with the next most(5000) to be "Rank: #2" and so on.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I have not, but can you show me an example so that I can test out the use and tell whether it works or not.

Comment: Would changing `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `mysql_fetch_array` make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY score DESC") or die("Could not allocate information!");
$rank = 0;
while(mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)){
    $rank++;
    echo "<b>Rank: </b>#$rank<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Yes. This gives me:

"Rank: #1
Rank: #2"

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `<ol>` [ordered list] tag:

```
<ol>
<?php while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)): ?>

    <li><?php echo $user['name']; ?></li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
</ol>
```

Guessing you want to display some property of the user [e.g. `name` or what you call it in your table], otherwise it does not makes much sense to display a list of numbers.

Anyway `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, please move to `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: What im trying to do is find where the user stands out of all others on the site and then display their "ranking".

Comment: This is what the code does [according to you original MySQL query].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY score DESC") or die("Could not allocate information!");
$rank = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {
     $rank++;
     if ($row['user_id'] == $current_pages_user_id){
           echo "<b>Rank: </b>#$rank<br/>";
     }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to display the users score. I want to take their score and figure out where the player stands throughout all of the other users

Comment: But I want anybody to see the persons rank... not just the profile owner

Comment: @RobertDoe Yes this would still work. the `$current_pages_user_id` variable would be set to the profile's owner's id, if that makes sense.

Comment: Do you have the ability to get the current profile's owner's id correctly?

Comment: @RobertDoe How does your system work? Does the user have it's own folder? Or does it use GET? If it uses GET to well, get the data, then you can use it to get the user's id number. It then checks if that id number is equal to the one produced by `$sql3`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql3)) {    
  $rank++;    
  echo "<b>#$rank. $user['name'] Score: </b> $user['score']<br />";    
}
```

But as hjpotter92 pointed out, look into using mysqli or pdo.

Comment: this displays ranks 1-2(I have 2 users). I only want to display 1 users rank which would be found on how much score they have

Comment: That is what im looking for. Now I want it to where it only shows the information for a specific username.

Comment: Aha, add to your sql query: WHERE userId = X or similar. Like:
'SELECT * FROM members WHERE userId = 5 ORDER BY score DESC' but then you can skip the loop and instead do:
`$sql = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM members WHERE userId = 5 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1');
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
echo "<b>#$rank. $user['name'] Score: </b> $user['score']<br />";`

Comment: What about the rank at that point? You cant query it and it cant count itself(not trying to sound like a jerk). So what would I do with the "$rank"?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Keep the loop and skip the where and limit part. Instead you can add an if statement in your loop to check if you have found the right user, something like `if($user['id'] == 5) echo "#$rank...`

Comment: Also check my other answer for an other kind of solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really are trying to do is something like this.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT member_name, score,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM members ORDER BY score DESC) AS rank
FROM members
WHERE member_id = 5
LIMIT 1") or die("Could not allocate information!");

$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "<b>#$member['rank']. $member['name']</b> Score:  $member['score']<br />";
```

As others mentioned before, check out the mysqli and pdo.